# Search output of p4 command

Tags: linux, grep, perforce, csh

I am trying to perform an action depending on the output of perforce commands. But it seems that pipping and greping/acking the command doesn't appear to pickup the output

e.g.

```
p4 sync -n $HOME/... | grep -c up
/homedirectory/... - file(s) up-to-date.
0

p4 sync -n $HOME/... | grep -c nope
/homedirectory/... - file(s) up-to-date.
0
```

Further example of what i'm trying to do:

```
if ( `p4 sync -n $HOME/... | grep -c "no such file"` == 0 ) then 
    if command
else
    do else command
endif
```

Is there anyway to read the output of a perforce command without having to write to a file then read the output? Ideally the command would be a single line.

Comment: Check STDERR too: `p4 sync -n $HOME/... 2>&1 | grep -c up`

Comment: It gives the output "Ambiguous output redirect."

Comment: Similar output  with: 
p4 sync -n $HOME/... >& | grep -c up 
"Ambiguous output redirect.". 
I have noticed when you check your history it seems to be adding a space randomly between the > and &. "p4 sync -n $HOME/... > & | grep -c up"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` isn't working because the "empty" messages like `no such file` and `up-to-date` go to stderr.  As @heemayl suggested one way to fix that is to do a redirect.

You can also fix this in a shell-independent way by using the `-s` or `-e` flags to `p4`:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -s sync
error: File(s) up-to-date.
exit: 0

C:\Perforce\test>p4 -e sync
error: File(s) up-to-date.
code0 554768772 (sub 388 sys 6 gen 17 args 1 sev 2 uniq 6532)
... code0 554768772
... fmt0 [%argc% - file(s)|File(s)] up-to-date.
... argc

exit: 0
```

Both of these flags redirect all output to stdout and also prepend every message with debugging information about the message itself.  If you're trying to grep for a particular message, for example, you can use the `-e` flag and grep for its unique code rather than the string.

Using the `-F` flag lets you reformat the output to include particular elements from the message dict that you see with `-e`, so if you want just the code:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -F %code0% sync
554768772
```

If you're trying to capture elements of the actual output, like file names, `-F` is even more useful:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -F %localPath% sync -n ...#1
c:\Perforce\test\0.f1
c:\Perforce\test\1.15
c:\Perforce\test\1.18
c:\Perforce\test\2.f1
c:\Perforce\test\2.f2
```